# Notepad ++, how can I have auto-correction of words in french with accents added when I write words with english keyboard?

Tags: notepad++, diacritics, autocorrect, french

I have an english keyboard. I can right click on the words after writing them. But it takes A LOT of time. Would anyone know any trick to have the words be corrected auto with the right accentuation or at least showing propositions to tab/chose the right one ?
Tried to find the solution on Google search but found nothing.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Buy a French keyboard. Or declare yours as a French one.

Comment: It is an option indeed; thanks, but ,y idea was to learn the possibilities through the app.